# Loading an image from local server using the emulator within a program

Tags: android

I wrote a code that it can load an image from local host within an `ImaheView` in my application. My code is correct. because when I test my program within my device and using the `PHPRunner` application, it can load the image from the `PHPRunner` application and I can see the image in my program.

Now, I want to load the image in my program using the emulator. I have `wamp server` in my windows and so I saved  my image in `www/in/image.jpg` folder.Also I changed the `url` address in my code as follows:

```
10.0.2.2:80/in/image.jpg
```

But when I run my program in emulator, it can not load the image from `wamp server`. Of course, when I open the browser through the emulator and I type the same code above:  `10.0.2.2:80/in/image.jpg` , I can see the image in the emulator through the browser.

But the problem is that I want to load the image when I run my application in emulator. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You should think of using A free file hosting service like somee. It's free and you can find tutorials on how to use it extensively. On that note, Android Emulators may listen to any Port, but I know for a fact that they would listen to :7541 so something like

```
10.0.2.2:7541
```

If that doesn't work or you are using a GenyMotion Emulator, you could try hosting the image on a file hosting site like I said or look at your ISP Provider IPv4 address Default Gateway if it is different